# installing tree.io on a centos 6

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

am trying to install tree.io http://tree.io/ on a centos 6 set up.

these are the steps am running.

1. checkout from the git repo git clone
   https://github.com/treeio/treeio.git ./
2. pip install -r requirements.pip

I am getting a error message in the console like this.

---

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg (from django-simple-captcha->-r requirements.pip (line 15))
Installing collected packages: hashlib, html5lib, oauth2, whoosh, python-dateutil, django-dajax, django-dajaxice, django-piston, unidecode, django-websocket, simplejson, johnny-cache, django-pandora, minidetector
  Running setup.py install for hashlib
    building '_sha' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c Modules/shamodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Modules/shamodule.o
    Modules/shamodule.c:18:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    Modules/shamodule.c:19:26: error: structmember.h: No such file or directory
    Modules/shamodule.c:47: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'PyObject_HEAD'
    Modules/shamodule.c:58: error: expected ')' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'SHAcopy':
    Modules/shamodule.c:76: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'
    Modules/shamodule.c:76: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'
    Modules/shamodule.c:77: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:77: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:78: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:78: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:79: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'
    Modules/shamodule.c:79: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'
    Modules/shamodule.c:80: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memcpy'
    Modules/shamodule.c:80: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
    Modules/shamodule.c:80: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:80: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:80: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:81: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:81: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:81: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_transform':
    Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: 'SHA_INT32' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: for each function it appears in.)
    Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: expected ';' before 'T'
    Modules/shamodule.c:166: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
    Modules/shamodule.c:166: error: 'W' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:166: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:166: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:167: warning: implicit declaration of function 'longReverse'
    Modules/shamodule.c:167: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:167: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'
    Modules/shamodule.c:175: error: 'A' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:175: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:176: error: 'B' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:176: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:177: error: 'C' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:177: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:178: error: 'D' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:178: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:179: error: 'E' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:179: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:180: error: 'WP' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:182: error: 'T' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:190: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:191: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:192: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:193: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:194: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_init':
    Modules/shamodule.c:224: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'
    Modules/shamodule.c:224: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'
    Modules/shamodule.c:226: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:227: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:228: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:229: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:230: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:231: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:232: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'
    Modules/shamodule.c:233: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_update':
    Modules/shamodule.c:242: error: 'SHA_INT32' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:242: error: expected ';' before 'clo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:244: error: 'clo' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:244: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:244: error: expected ')' before 'count'
    Modules/shamodule.c:245: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:246: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'
    Modules/shamodule.c:248: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:249: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'
    Modules/shamodule.c:249: error: expected ';' before 'count'
    Modules/shamodule.c:250: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:251: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:255: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
    Modules/shamodule.c:255: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:255: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:258: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:259: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c:267: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
    Modules/shamodule.c:267: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:272: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'
    Modules/shamodule.c:272: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:273: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'
    Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_final':
    Modules/shamodule.c:282: error: 'SHA_INT32' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:282: error: expected ';' before 'lo_bit_count'
    Modules/shamodule.c:284: error: 'lo_bit_count' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:284: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'
    Modules/shamodule.c:285: error: 'hi_bit_count' undeclared (first use in this function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:285: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'
    Modules/shamodule.c:287: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:289: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memset'
    Modules/shamodule.c:289: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
    Modules/shamodule.c:289: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:292: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:295: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'
    Modules/shamodule.c:295: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:301: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:302: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:303: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:304: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:305: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:306: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:307: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:308: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'
    Modules/shamodule.c:310: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:311: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:312: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:313: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:314: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:315: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:316: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:317: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:318: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:319: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:320: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:321: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:322: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:323: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:324: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:325: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:326: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:327: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:328: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c:329: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'
    Modules/shamodule.c: At top level:
    Modules/shamodule.c:338: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHAtype'
    Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'newSHAobject':
    Modules/shamodule.c:344: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyObject_New'
    Modules/shamodule.c:344: error: expected expression before 'SHAobject'
    Modules/shamodule.c: At top level:
    Modules/shamodule.c:350: error: expected ')' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:358: error: expected ')' before string constant
    Modules/shamodule.c:360: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:373: error: expected ')' before string constant
    Modules/shamodule.c:375: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:387: error: expected ')' before string constant
    Modules/shamodule.c:389: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:426: error: expected ')' before string constant
    Modules/shamodule.c:428: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:443: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHA_methods'
    Modules/shamodule.c:451: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:457: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:463: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:469: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHA_getseters'
    Modules/shamodule.c:491: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHAtype'
    Modules/shamodule.c:530: error: expected ')' before string constant
    Modules/shamodule.c:534: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
    Modules/shamodule.c:565: error: array type has incomplete element type
    Modules/shamodule.c:566: error: 'PyCFunction' undeclared here (not in a function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:566: error: expected '}' before 'SHA_new'
    Modules/shamodule.c:567: error: 'NULL' undeclared here (not in a function)
    Modules/shamodule.c:576: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'init_sha'
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/hashlib/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wHY9zp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building '_sha' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c Modules/shamodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Modules/shamodule.o

Modules/shamodule.c:18:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Modules/shamodule.c:19:26: error: structmember.h: No such file or directory

Modules/shamodule.c:47: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'PyObject_HEAD'

Modules/shamodule.c:58: error: expected ')' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'SHAcopy':

Modules/shamodule.c:76: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'

Modules/shamodule.c:76: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'

Modules/shamodule.c:77: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:77: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:78: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:78: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:79: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'

Modules/shamodule.c:79: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'

Modules/shamodule.c:80: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memcpy'

Modules/shamodule.c:80: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'

Modules/shamodule.c:80: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:80: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:80: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:81: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:81: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:81: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_transform':

Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: 'SHA_INT32' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: for each function it appears in.)

Modules/shamodule.c:164: error: expected ';' before 'T'

Modules/shamodule.c:166: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'

Modules/shamodule.c:166: error: 'W' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:166: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:166: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:167: warning: implicit declaration of function 'longReverse'

Modules/shamodule.c:167: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:167: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'

Modules/shamodule.c:175: error: 'A' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:175: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:176: error: 'B' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:176: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:177: error: 'C' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:177: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:178: error: 'D' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:178: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:179: error: 'E' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:179: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:180: error: 'WP' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:182: error: 'T' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:190: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:191: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:192: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:193: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:194: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_init':

Modules/shamodule.c:224: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'

Modules/shamodule.c:224: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'Endianness'

Modules/shamodule.c:226: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:227: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:228: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:229: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:230: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:231: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:232: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'

Modules/shamodule.c:233: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_update':

Modules/shamodule.c:242: error: 'SHA_INT32' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:242: error: expected ';' before 'clo'

Modules/shamodule.c:244: error: 'clo' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:244: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:244: error: expected ')' before 'count'

Modules/shamodule.c:245: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:246: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'

Modules/shamodule.c:248: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:249: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'

Modules/shamodule.c:249: error: expected ';' before 'count'

Modules/shamodule.c:250: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:251: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:255: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'

Modules/shamodule.c:255: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:255: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:258: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:259: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c:267: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'

Modules/shamodule.c:267: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:272: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memcpy'

Modules/shamodule.c:272: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:273: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'local'

Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'sha_final':

Modules/shamodule.c:282: error: 'SHA_INT32' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:282: error: expected ';' before 'lo_bit_count'

Modules/shamodule.c:284: error: 'lo_bit_count' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:284: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_lo'

Modules/shamodule.c:285: error: 'hi_bit_count' undeclared (first use in this function)

Modules/shamodule.c:285: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'count_hi'

Modules/shamodule.c:287: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:289: warning: implicit declaration of function 'memset'

Modules/shamodule.c:289: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'

Modules/shamodule.c:289: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:292: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:295: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'memset'

Modules/shamodule.c:295: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:301: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:302: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:303: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:304: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:305: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:306: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:307: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:308: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'data'

Modules/shamodule.c:310: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:311: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:312: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:313: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:314: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:315: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:316: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:317: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:318: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:319: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:320: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:321: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:322: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:323: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:324: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:325: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:326: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:327: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:328: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c:329: error: 'SHAobject' has no member named 'digest'

Modules/shamodule.c: At top level:

Modules/shamodule.c:338: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHAtype'

Modules/shamodule.c: In function 'newSHAobject':

Modules/shamodule.c:344: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyObject_New'

Modules/shamodule.c:344: error: expected expression before 'SHAobject'

Modules/shamodule.c: At top level:

Modules/shamodule.c:350: error: expected ')' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:358: error: expected ')' before string constant

Modules/shamodule.c:360: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:373: error: expected ')' before string constant

Modules/shamodule.c:375: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:387: error: expected ')' before string constant

Modules/shamodule.c:389: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:426: error: expected ')' before string constant

Modules/shamodule.c:428: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:443: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHA_methods'

Modules/shamodule.c:451: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:457: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:463: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:469: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHA_getseters'

Modules/shamodule.c:491: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'SHAtype'

Modules/shamodule.c:530: error: expected ')' before string constant

Modules/shamodule.c:534: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Modules/shamodule.c:565: error: array type has incomplete element type

Modules/shamodule.c:566: error: 'PyCFunction' undeclared here (not in a function)

Modules/shamodule.c:566: error: expected '}' before 'SHA_new'

Modules/shamodule.c:567: error: 'NULL' undeclared here (not in a function)

Modules/shamodule.c:576: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'init_sha'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-root/hashlib/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wHY9zp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/hashlib
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

can someone please help with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install python27-devel package first.

```
yum install python27-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

i didnt have the python-devel

installed it using

```
yum  install python-devel.x86_64
```

and its solved;